# Webpack + Typescript + Angularjs - System.Register (Webpack Warning)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

I have the following setup:

- Webpack v3.6.0
- Typescript v2.5.2
- AngularJS v1.4.8

I'm trying to import a constant file into my service:

```
// const.ts
const TEST_CONSTANT = {
  names: [
    'const1'
  ]
};

default export TEST_CONSTANT;

// service.ts
import TEST_CONSTANT from 'const';

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

I'm using awesome-typescript-loader:

```
[...]
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
  },
  exclude: /node_modules/,
},
[...]
```

However, when I try to run/build I got the following warning:

> WARNING in ./constants/.js System.register is not
>   supported by webpack.

After that, I'm not able to run the application because of this. Any suggestions? I'm using commonjs at TS config file.